# Why is Octave's function call overhead so much larger than both Matlab's and Python's?

Tags: performance, matlab, function, optimization, octave

I have two pieces of code in Python and Octave that are structurally identical. However, the Python version, implemented with numpy and scipy, is ~5x faster. I did a profile of the code, and I found that the main culprit in the Octave code is 6 functions repeatedly called thousands of times in a loop. These functions only compute numerical expressions, e.g. cos, cosh, so I was surprised by how much time they were consuming (For reference, the two codes both run under 2 seconds.)

I researched this strange phenomenon online and read a [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221663825_Function_call_overhead_benchmarks_with_MATLAB_Octave_Python_Cythonand_C) that showed that the function overhead in Octave, i.e. the setup needed for the function to start executing the actual function code in the function's body and cleaning it up afterwards, is approximately 30 times larger than that of Matlab and approximately 100 times larger than that of Python.

This occurrence greatly baffles me--**How is it possible that calling a function from Octave can be *this* much slower than calling a function in the two other similar languages? Furthermore, is there any way to remedy this reduction in speed besides copying and pasting the function itself into the body of the loop?**

EDIT: I've posted the main for loop from my code. It's an iterative implementation of newton's method for multiple equations, so I'm not sure how it could be vectorized.

```
for k = 1:10    
  for l = 1:50
    % matrix of derivatives of equations with respect to variables
    a = [dEq1_dq1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j), dEq1_dq2(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j); dEq2_dq1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j), dEq2_dq2(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j)];

    % vector of equations
    b = [Eq1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j); Eq2(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j)];

    % solution to ax=b
    x = a \ b;

    % iteratively update q
    q1 -= beta*x(1);
    q2 -= beta*x(2);
  endfor

  for l = 1:50
    a = [dEp1_dp1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j), dEp1_dp2(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j); dEp2_dp1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j), dEp2_dp2(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j)];
    b = [Ep1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j); Ep2(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j)];
    x = a \ b;

    p1 -= beta*x(1);
    p2 -= beta*x(2);
  endfor
endfor

...

% derivatives of implicit equations with respect to variables
function val = dEp1_dp1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j)
  % symmetric
  if mod(i, 2) == 1
    val = p1/(2*cos(p1/2)**2)+tan(p1/2);
  % anti-symmetric
  else
    val = tan(p1/2)/(p1**2)-1/(2*p1*cos(p1/2)**2);
  endif
end

...

function val = Ep1(p1, p2, q1, q2, i, j)    
  if mod(i, 2) == 1
    val = p2*tanh(p2/2)+p1*tan(p1/2);
  else
    val = (1/p2)*tanh(p2/2)-(1/p1)*tan(p1/2);
  endif
end

...
```

Comment: All 3 are interpreted languages and incur some overhead at functions calls. I don't find it all that surprising that both Python and Matlab archived better optimizations than Octave considering that they are much larger projects (larger user base, more development happening, etc.). In particular, Matlab uses a Just-In-Time (JIT) accelerator that will be faster in a number of cases. As to how you can avoid this problem: vectorize your code and don't use loops unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @rth Thanks for the insightful information. Unfortunately, my code is an iterative implementation of newton's method (with several equations), so I'm not sure how it could be vectorized. Is there any possible solution for this type of case? Would it also help if I posted my code?

Answer (score 4):

Comparing performance between languages is tricky business. Octave will tell you right away that you should vectorize your code. That's what the language was designed for. Python compiles his code into byte-code and that will allow for optimizations. Matlab has JIT which does the same. But not Octave. Octave will do exactly what you wrote, and will read your program one line at a time. This means that your performance will suffer if you don't write good code.

And while there might be a large overhead for making a function call (I didn't check your numbers), that's not so important if you only make a few functions calls. You will often be dealing with large arrays, so it's the actual "sciency" computations that should be causing your performance issues (unless of course, you don't write proper Octave programs and use unnecessary loops).

The functions you mentioned, `cos` and `cosh`, will accept a vector so there's is no need to use a for loop for it.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. This is actually my first time programming a large-scale program in Octave--I've primarily worked with Python in the past. I understand that vectorization significantly expedites code due to low-level CPU optimizations that the compiler makes, but I'm not sure how to vectorize my code in this case--It's an iterative implementation of newton's method for multiple equations. I've edited my code into the question above, and I would really appreciate it if you could take a look. :)

Comment: @VedaadShakib actually vectorizing your code is a different question. And it will probably require knowledge of numerical analysis that I don't have. Might be important to note that not all languages are suitable for everything. If you can't vectorize your code, and it really requires a large number of iterations with many function calls, Octave will be a poor choice to solve your issue. But you can use liboctave which has a very nice C++ interface.

Comment: Okay, I might consider "acquiring" a version of Matlab and giving it a shot there. Thanks anyways!